# Integration : different answers from two methods

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

[image: my work]

There seems to be no way to get these expressions from both the methods to match. I know the arbitrary constant could vary in different methods but even the strcture of both these expressions are not close to same.

I know there is no calculation error because I differentiated the final expressions in both the methods to get the starting integrand.

Please tell me why the expressions don't match then.

Comment: What expressions might those be?

Comment: It just wouldn't let me post the image. I have made the edits now.

Comment: Would you let me know which step did I do wrong?

Comment: I retract my statement. Both are correct. They differ in their constant term.

Comment: Can ypu show me how?

Comment: Expand $\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan a+\tan b}{1+\tan a\tan b}$ on the first answer and rearrange and you should be able to get something like the second.

Comment: I tried that but they still won't match.

Comment: Useful information: $\tan\left(\frac{\tan^{-1}(3/4)}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @JoeyZou I am getting two values of that expression : 1/3 and 3 on solving the quadratic. How did you reject the latter?

Comment: 1)  The other value should be $-3$. 2) Your angle satisfies $\sin\alpha = 3/5$ and $\cos\alpha = 4/5$, so it lies in the first quadrant. That means its half angle should lie either in the first or third quadrants, and in both cases $\tan$ is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two terms are equivalent :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac15\tan\left({\frac{x-\tan^{-1}\frac34}{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{3\tan\frac{x}{2} -1}{3+\tan\frac{x}{2}}\right)=\frac15\left(\frac{3\tan\frac{x}{2} +9 -10}{3+\tan\frac{x}{2}}\right)$$
$$=\frac35 +\frac{-2}{\tan\frac{x}{2} +3}$$

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: @user362725 I think this will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where you made an error if you don't show your working, your result, or even the problem you're trying to solve.

But that said, I do know a lot of people have trouble seeing "the constants of integration are just different" when it's not directly obvious. For example, they would have trouble recognizing that both solutions

$$ \sin^2 x + C_1  \qquad \qquad -\cos^2 x + C_2 $$

are the same solution, because they did not think to check beyond simply adding a number to the formal expression.

If you really think you have two equal results, consider it a new math problem to see if the two results are the same or different. e.g. do one of the following two things:

> Solve for the constant $A$ in $\sin^2 x + A = -\cos^2 x$

to see that they really are equal, or

> Find two values $a$ and $b$ so that $(\sin^2 a) - (-\cos^2 a) \neq (\sin^2 b) - (-\cos^2 b)$ have different values.

to see that they really *aren't* equal. (and so there really must be some mistake or oversight)

Comment: Please see the edits now. I have shown the working in the image. I think I considered every possible manipulation I knew but nothing worked out.